# Unable to map multiple nested array data in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I am confused how can I map multiple nested array of data in react and display them in a table.

The table should contain the details of the collection: **title**, **location**, **description** and **keywords** from the collection.

Here is my react code

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://images-api.nasa.gov/search?media_type=image")
      .then((response) => {
        setData(response.data);
      })
      .then(
        (response) => {},
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
  }, []);
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="App grid  place-content-center h-screen gap-24">
      <form className="">
        <label
          for="default-search"
          class="mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 sr-only dark:text-gray-300"
        >
          Search
        </label>
        <div class="relative">
          <div class="flex absolute inset-y-0 left-0 items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none">
            <svg
              class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"
              fill="none"
              stroke="currentColor"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            >
              <path
                stroke-linecap="round"
                stroke-linejoin="round"
                stroke-width="2"
                d="M21 21l-6-6m2-5a7 7 0 11-14 0 7 7 0 0114 0z"
              ></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <input
            type="search"
            id="default-search"
            class="focus:ring-0 outline-none block p-4 pl-10 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
            placeholder="Search Mockups, Logos..."
            required
          />
          <button
            type="submit"
            class="text-white absolute right-2.5 bottom-2.5 bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800"
          >
            Search
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="container flex justify-center mx-auto">
        <div class="flex flex-col">
          <div class="w-full">
            <div class="border-b border-gray-200 shadow">
              <table>
                <thead class="bg-gray-50">
                  <tr>
                    <th class="px-6 py-2 text-xs text-gray-500">title</th>
                    <th class="px-6 py-2 text-xs text-gray-500">location</th>
                    <th class="px-6 py-2 text-xs text-gray-500">description</th>
                    <th class="px-6 py-2 text-xs text-gray-500">keywords</th>
                    <th class="px-6 py-2 text-xs text-gray-500">Edit</th>
                    <th class="px-6 py-2 text-xs text-gray-500">Delete</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="bg-white">
                  {data?.collection?.items?.map((items) => {
                    {
                      items?.data?.map((item) => {
                        <tr class="whitespace-nowrap">
                          <td class="px-6 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
                            {item?.data?.title}
                          </td>
                          <td class="px-6 py-4">
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-900">
                              {item?.data?.location}
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="px-6 py-4">
                            <div class="text-sm text-gray-500">
                              {item?.data?.description}
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td class="px-6 py-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
                            {item?.data?.keywords}
                          </td>
                          <td class="px-6 py-4">
                            <a
                              href="#"
                              class="px-4 py-1 text-sm text-white bg-blue-400 rounded"
                            >
                              Edit
                            </a>
                          </td>
                          <td class="px-6 py-4">
                            <a
                              href="#"
                              class="px-4 py-1 text-sm text-white bg-red-400 rounded"
                            >
                              Delete
                            </a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>;
                      });
                    }
                  })}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the nested array of data.

```
"collection": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "href": "http://images-api.nasa.gov/search?media_type=image",
        "items": [
            {
                "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-2009-4794/collection.json",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "center": "KSC",
                        "title": "KSC-2009-4794",
                        "location": "Kennedy Space Center, FL",
                        "nasa_id": "KSC-2009-4794",
                        "media_type": "image",
                        "date_created": "2009-08-19T00:00:00Z",
                        "description": "CAPE CANAVERAL, Fla. – In NASA Kennedy Space Center's Orbiter Processing Facility 2, workers begin removing the forward reaction control system, or FRCS, from space shuttle Endeavour's forward fuselage nose area. The FRCS provides the thrust for attitude (rotational) maneuvers (pitch, yaw and roll) and for small velocity changes along the orbiter axis (translation maneuvers). Endeavour is designated as the shuttle for the STS-130 mission, targeted for launch in February 2010.  Photo credit: NASA/Jack Pfaller"
                    }
                ],
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-2009-4794/KSC-2009-4794~thumb.jpg",
                        "rel": "preview",
                        "render": "image"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-2009-4795/collection.json",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "center": "KSC",
                        "title": "KSC-2009-4795",
                        "location": "Kennedy Space Center, FL",
                        "nasa_id": "KSC-2009-4795",
                        "media_type": "image",
                        "date_created": "2009-08-19T00:00:00Z",
                        "description": "CAPE CANAVERAL, Fla. – In NASA Kennedy Space Center's Orbiter Processing Facility 2, a worker removes the forward reaction control system, or FRCS, from space shuttle Endeavour's forward fuselage nose area. The FRCS provides the thrust for attitude (rotational) maneuvers (pitch, yaw and roll) and for small velocity changes along the orbiter axis (translation maneuvers). Endeavour is designated as the shuttle for the STS-130 mission, targeted for launch in February 2010.  Photo credit: NASA/Jack Pfaller"
                    }
                ],
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-2009-4795/KSC-2009-4795~thumb.jpg",
                        "rel": "preview",
                        "render": "image"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-2009-4798/collection.json",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "center": "KSC",
                        "title": "KSC-2009-4798",
                        "location": "Kennedy Space Center, FL",
                        "nasa_id": "KSC-2009-4798",
                        "media_type": "image",
                        "date_created": "2009-08-20T00:00:00Z",
                        "description": "CAPE CANAVERAL, Fla. – The 327-foot tall Ares I-X rocket stretches into the upper regions of NASA Kennedy Space Center's Vehicle Assembly Building.  The rocket is stacked on the mobile launcher platform in High Bay 3.  Mission, program and NASA decals are lined up on the stack below the U.S. flag.  Five super stacks make up the upper stage that are integrated with the four-segment solid rocket booster first stage below.  Ares I-X is the test vehicle for the Ares I, which is part of the Constellation Program to return men to the moon and beyond. The Ares I-X flight test is targeted for  Oct. 31.  Photo credit: NASA/Jack Pfaller"
                    }
                ],
                "links": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://images-assets.nasa.gov/image/KSC-2009-4798/KSC-2009-4798~thumb.jpg",
                        "rel": "preview",
                        "render": "image"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

How can I render **title**, **location**, **description** and **keywords** from the collection from the array of data?

Comment: in your nested map `{item?.data?.title}` should just be `{item.title}` etc. You're already mapping over `items.data` and the individual `item` doesn't have a `data` property. Also no need for optional chaining on single props.

Comment: What error you're getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not returning after mapping, for example this **WILL NOT WORK**:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.items.map((e) => {
        <div>
          {e.data.map((s) => (
            <div>
              <div>{s.title}</div>
              <div>{s.location}</div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>;
      })}
    </div>
  )
```

ESLINT will through a warning says `Expected to return a value in arrow function. (array-callback-return)`
that means you need either to add a `return` statement after the map or remove the curly brackets `{}`. for example ***solution A*** remove curly brackets :

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.items.map((e) => 
        <div>
          {e.data.map((s) => (
            <div>
              <div>{s.title}</div>
              <div>{s.location}</div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

***solution B*** add the return statement:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.items.map((e) => {
        return (
          <div>
            {e.data.map((s) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <div>{s.title}</div>
                  <div>{s.location}</div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: sandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-browser-1gvnxq?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would map to display Titles and the URL in links/href:

(I'm using Bootstrap 5 to create a photo/gallery/grid with the pictures from href + title with a limit of 15 letters per title (.substring(0, 15)+"...") )

```
<div className='p-3 d-flex flex-wrap'>

    {data?.collection?.items?.map((items) => {
        return(
            <>
                {items?.links?.map((links) => {
                    console.log(links);
                    return(
    <Row className='ms-3  p-1'>
    <Col className='text-center'>                
    <img
    width={180}
    height={180}
    alt="171x180"
    src={links?.href}
    className=" border border-dark"
  />
  {items?.data?.map((data) => {
    return(
        <>
          <p>{data?.title.substring(0,15)+"..."}</p>
        </>
    )
  })}
        </Col>
        </Row>
  )})}
        </>    
        )
    })}
</div>
```